# use array as an id in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I this array:

```
arrayHAY["rat","cat","hat","mat","bat"];
```

And these elements:

```
<div id="rat"></div>
<div id="cat"></div>
<div id="hat"></div>
<div id="mat"></div>
<div id="bat"></div>
```

My question is how can I use the array to loop through each of those elements and do something to it?

Something like this:

```
var nameOfarray = document.getElementByID('.arrayHAY[i].value')
var lengthOfArray = nameOfarray.length;                            
for(var i=0; i<lengthOfArray; i++) {
// do something
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: a JS array has absolutely nothing to do with the DOM. It's just a JS variable that happens to contain an array object. There's no "id" or "getElementById" you do to "find" that variable, it's just a variable. Once you've got the array, it's like any other array that you want to loop on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
for (var i = 0, l = arrayHAY.length; i < l; ++i) {
  var selected = document.getElementById(arrayHAY[i]);
  // your own code would be here
}
```

This would loop and select each element.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
var arrayHAY = ["rat","cat","hat","mat","bat"];

for (var i = 0, l = arrayHAY.length; i < l; ++i) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(arrayHAY[i]);
  // now do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are close. Try to understand what you are doing. You have `id`s of elements in an array. You need to get the elements corresponding to the `id`, so use each element as the id in `document.getElementById`.

```
var lengthOfArray = nameOfarray.length;                            
for(var i=0; i<lengthOfArray; i++) {
    var element = document.getElementByID(arrayHAY[i].value) //No quotes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays (with [ECMAScript 5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript)) you can do:

```
['rat', 'cat', 'hat', 'mat', 'bat'].forEach(function(id) {
    var element = this.getElementById(id);
    console.log('Selected Element: ', element);
}, document);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for( var i=0; i<arrayHay.length; i++ )
{

    document.getElementsById(arrayHay[i]).value; // access value from outside

}
```